# change to text using jquery and ajax

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, post

I have a script to change my button from "Approve" to "Approved" in my jquery and ajax but the problem is if I click the first row the other row will change to "Approved" also.

This is my button,

```
<td>
    <button type="button" class="btn indigo approve_button"
            onclick='approve_account("<?php echo $row['ID_users'];?>")'>Approve
   </button>
</td>
```

And this is my jquery and ajax script:

```
function approve_account(IDuser){

    $(document).ready(function(){
      console.log(IDuser);
          $.ajax({
            url: "../Queries/approve_user.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {"IDuser":IDuser},
            success: function(yey){
              $(".approve_button").text("Approved");
              console.log(yey);
              alert(yey);
            }
          });
      });
}
```

Also and if i refresh the page the buttons resets back to "Approve".

Screenshot: the result when the 1st row button is clicked:

[image: if 1st row button click]

Help please? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, don't put `$(document).ready()` inside another function. The ready event occurs when the DOM (document object model) has been loaded. Because this event occurs after the document is ready, it is a good place to have all other jQuery events and functions. [document-ready doc](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/)

Next, you need to refine your selector to target only the current HTML element not ALL members of the `.approve_button` class. This is easier done without the inline `onclick` attribute. You can then use a data attribute to pass the IDUser value from the button.

HTML:

```
<td><button type="button" class="btn indigo approve_button"
            data-iduser="<?php echo $row['ID_users']; ?>">Approve</button></td>
```

JS:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".approve_button").click(function () {
        var btn = $(this),
            IDuser = $(this).data('iduser');

        console.log(IDuser);
        $.ajax({
            url: "../Queries/approve_user.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: {"IDuser": IDuser},
            success: function (yey) {
                btn.text("Approved");
                console.log(yey);
                alert(yey);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help btw, that works actually but the variable IDuser is undefined when I click it but if I inspect that button it has a value.

Comment: You're welcome. If the answer works for you and you feel it's the best one, you can mark it as Accepted

Comment: the variable IDuser is undefined in the script sir why is that?

Comment: Instead of using the onclick attribute I use a data attribute in the button to pass that IDuser that you were passing before

Comment: Oh ok sir but this IDuser = $(this).data('IDuser'); is undefined in the script.

Comment: sorry, it doesn't like the capitalization in the naming. I changed it

Comment: It finally works. Thank you so much. You're a lifesaver. :)